# node-minify for multiple files cannot find the file names

Tags: node.js, node-modules, minify

Using node-minify and attempting to minify all the HTML files in a given folder and write them to an output folder, the following snippet writes a file called '.min.html' i.e. it cannot find the original file name using $1.

```
var comp = require('node-minify');
comp.minify({
  compressor: 'html-minifier',
  input: 'in/*.html',
  output: 'out/$1.min.html',
  callback: function(err, min) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Is this a bug or is there some other way to get the file name?

Answer (score 0):

This solution described here solved the issue: https://github.com/srod/node-minify/issues/856